# SNOWFLAKE: Pivot Issue, rows to columns not working

Tags: sql, pivot, multiple-columns, rows, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

everyone I am trying to convert two timestamp columns that have multiple rows per id. I would like to have instead of rows a column for both of them.

The timestamp_meaning tells us what the timestamp1 shows for example
0 - 5 represent airport 1

when timestamp_menaing = 0 ( 0 = airport 1)

timestamp 1: arrival at airport 1
timestamp 2: depart at airport 1

I have the following structure of the table

```
ID, timestamp1 timestamp2 timestamp_meaning
1   xx          xx              0
1   xx          xx              1
1   xx          xx              2
2   xx          xx              0
2   xx          xx              1
3   xx          xx              0
```

(timestamp meaning differs for every id, each number represents a different meaning for the timestamps)

I would like to see the results as follows:

```
id  timestamp1_0, timestamp1_1, timestamp1_2  timestamp1_3  timestamp2_0 timestamp2_1 timestamp2_2, timestamp_2_3
1    xx              xx             xx           NULL         XX            XX          XX                       
2    xx              xx             NULL         NULL         XX            XX          NULL
3    xx              NULL           NULL         NULL         XX           NULL
```

timestamp1_2: where 1 is the column timestamp1 and _2 corresponds to the timestamp_meaning value.

So basically a split of timestamp 1 and timestamp from row to columns.

I tried the code with one of the timestamp column:

```
select * from table
    
    pivot(listagg(timestamp1) for timestamp_meaning in (0,1,2,3,4,5)) as timestamps
order by ID ;
```

where timestamp1 = arrival
and timestamp_meaning = airport 1

current results are in diagonals

```
ID   0    1     2   3
 1    xx   -    -  -
 1         xx   
 1             xx  -
```

timestamp1 : arrival timestamp2 : depart

I would expect the results to be one row per id, showing all the columns for timestamp1 and timestamp2. I would also like to rename the 0,1,2,3 to airport1_arrival
similarly for timestamp2 airport1_depart

right now it shows airport 1, airport 2 .....  i.e 0,1,2,3 (in the output) which does tell me that it's airport 1 but the values are not clear, whether they are from arrival or departure.

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       listagg(case when timestamp_meaning = 0 then timestamp end),
       listagg(case when timestamp_meaning = 1 then timestamp end),
       listagg(case when timestamp_meaning = 2 then timestamp end),
       listagg(case when timestamp_meaning = 3 then timestamp end),
       listagg(case when timestamp_meaning = 4 then timestamp end),
       listagg(case when timestamp_meaning = 5 then timestamp end)
from table
group by id;
```

Comment: this would mean 10 list_agg statements assuming 5 for arrival 5 for departure for timestamp1 and 2, is there not an efficient way to do this :( ? because in some cases there are 10 values for timestamp_meaning

Comment: @trillion . . . This is about the question that was asked that refers to 6 values.  But yes, you can extend this logic to more values or combine values from different columns.

Comment: I understand that but is there a more efficient way instead of writing 10 -20 lines of case when based on total timestamp meaning values?

Comment: @trillion . . . Copy/paste/edit is quite simple.  You can also do that in a spreadsheet.